# How to put a tableview inside one of the cell of another tableView? any idea?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uitableview

In one of the cell of a tableView, i want to put another tableView(toyTable for example). Can anyone help me in this?  I have created a tableView (main one) and another tableview in my project. Now in my main tableView, i have many cells and in one of the cell, i want that another table(toyTable) to be present in the cell.

Comment: why you need inside of another table. any special reason for that

Comment: what you try to achieving

Comment: @santhu: Can you please show me the pic of that output that of that answer which is ticked correct in the link you posted? please.. i need it badly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lets say you have two tables.

Make properties for both of them

```
// This one might be connected as an outlet with your storyboard
@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableViewController *mainTable;
// This one should be in the .m file
@property (nonatomic) UITableViewController *toyTable;
```

Implement delegate and datasource protocol methods for each.

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    if (tableView == self.mainTable) {
        return 2;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (tableView == self.mainTable) {
        return 10;
    } else {
        return 5;
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (tableView == self.mainTable) {
        // If this is the indexPath for the cell that should contain 
        // the nested table view, initialize your self.toyTable, set 
        // datasource and delegate etc.
        // Else configure your default outer cell
    } else {
        // Configure the cells of your self.toyTable;
    }
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (tableView == self.mainTable) {
        // If this is any normal outer cell
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
        // If this is the outer cell that contains self.toyTable
        return some bigger value (if desired)
    } else {
        // The height of the inner cell
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
    }
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (tableView == self.mainTable) {
        // If this is the outer cell that contains self.toyTable
        // You should ignore the selection
        // Else handle it according to your needs
    } else {
        // Handle click on inner cell
    }
}
```

If you are using a static table view as your mainTable, you can directly drag a table view onto one of your static cells and define prototype cells etc for it.

Answer (score 1):

Putting table view inside table cell is a bad design. Insert `toyTable` as a *section* of main table view instead.

Comment: Why is it better to add a 2nd table view as a section instead as a child of a contentview? are you thinking of additional features like section collapsing?

Comment: @Jano I guess, there will be issues with reusing cells of inner table view. Collapsing could be a responsibility of a table data source.

Answer (score 0):

Why are u doing this because its a bad idea for nesting the tableview instead UITableview already having expand and collapsing property.
Use below link for reference http://www.cocoanetics.com/2011/03/expandingcollapsing-tableview-sections/

Answer (score 0):

In cellForRowAtIndexPath add that table and do the code like this :

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

   if (tableView == mainTable) {
     //do this for main table
   }
   else { 
     //do this for second table
   }

}
```